# How to build OpenSSL on Android/Linux ?

Tags: android, android-ndk, g++, openssl

Hi
I'm in need to build OpenSSL lib for Android NDK r5b, today it will be second day of my ... useles fight. Here is short list what i've done

1. Downloaded: https://github.com/fries/android-external-openssl/
2. As i found here on StackOverflow fixed  .S <->.s  problem
3. Crypto gets builded... until i get this message:

---

/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
SharedLibrary  : libcrypto.so
arm-linux-androideabi-g++.exe: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
make: *** [/cygdrive/c/AndroidDev/AndroidOpenSSL/obj/local/armeabi/libcrypto.so]
 Error 1***

It's 10 years when i last time used make, and i was sure it's problem with g++ path. Added some debug to toolchain, and got:

TOOLCHAIN_NAME: arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3
TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX: /cygdrive/c/Android_NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-

both looks fine for me, as /cygdrive/c/Android_NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/ does exist, and arm-linux-androideabi-g++.exe is right there :(

Any one ever had this same problem? I realy have no idea where to look any future :(
Will be appreciative for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is also to shorten the openssl build path, eg. from c:\code\openssl-android to just c:\ssl

Answer (score 2):

Looks like only i had such problem. Here is a solution i found, mayby someone will figure out why this happend.
Saved command line to separate file called **bild_data** (output from ndk-build), then removed from it g++ call, this way my build file had only list of files and needed flags. Then i just executed from cygwin **arm-linux-androideabi-g++ @build_data**
After that i had my 'precious' libcrypto.so, **ndk-build** executed again with libcrypto.so alerdy builded from command line, builded openssl library.
For me it looks like command line that was over 31kb did not fit to cygwin buffer :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem building on Windows (cygwin), and shortening the path to the project directory (see mango's answer) is what worked for me.