# Compiling the latest OpenSSL for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, openssl

I am trying to generate the shared library for the (.so) files of the OpenSSL1.0.1c for the Android. I found that they have added three options for compiling for the Android in the android script.

```
./Configure android-armv7  (or)
./Configure android-x86    (or)
./Configure android
```

once I configured for the OS and then try to compile, its throwing errors.
Currently I am working x86 windows7 and installed Cygwin, Android sdk R20, Android NDK r8

```
sh-4.1$ make
making all in crypto...
make[1]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/d/SourceCodes/OpenSSL/openssl-1.0.1c/crypto'
gcc -I. -I.. -I../include  -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -march=armv7-a -mandroid -I/include -B/lib -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOP
ENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM   -c -o cryptlib.o cryptlib.c
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-mandroid"
cryptlib.c:1:0: error: bad value (armv7-a) for -march= switch
<builtin>: recipe for target `cryptlib.o' failed
make[1]: *** [cryptlib.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/d/SourceCodes/OpenSSL/openssl-1.0.1c/crypto'
Makefile:278: recipe for target `build_crypto' failed
make: *** [build_crypto] Error 1
sh-4.1$
```

Please let me know if anyone faced the similar issue and got the solution for resolving the same.

Comment: http://freelancer-suman.blogspot.in/p/steps-for-porting-openssl-for-android.html

Comment: https://github.com/aluvalasuman/OpenSSL1.0.1cForAndroid

Comment: You should probably use the instructions provided by the project. Also see [OpenSSL and Android](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android) from the OpenSSL wiki. It used to be an answer below, but one of the moderators deleted it.

Comment: @jww there's not much point in looking at the instructions on the openssl wiki.  They don't have enough information to actually build for android.  (You'll notice things like "Cross-compile environment for Android on ARMv7 and x86" - great, thanks, what about the rest of the architectures Android supports?)

Comment: The [OpenSSL wiki](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android) is outdated both on NDK side and on the OpenSSL side.

Answer (score 56):

I would seriously not advise to grab anything outside of the official OpenSSL web site. You cannot take a chance when dealing with cryptography and security.

The only problem that I see is that you are using your host's gcc rather than using android's cross compilers.

Here is how I would compile the official OpenSSL on Ubuntu 14.04LTS (this works with OpenSSL 1.0.1g)

From your home folder, run the following commands:

```
tar xzvf ~/Downloads/openssl-1.0.1g.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.1g
export NDK=~/android-ndk-r9d
$NDK/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-9 --toolchain=arm-linux-androideabi-4.6 --install-dir=`pwd`/android-toolchain-arm
export TOOLCHAIN_PATH=`pwd`/android-toolchain-arm/bin
export TOOL=arm-linux-androideabi
export NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME=${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/${TOOL}
export CC=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-gcc
export CXX=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-g++
export LINK=${CXX}
export LD=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-ld
export AR=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-ar
export RANLIB=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-ranlib
export STRIP=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-strip
export ARCH_FLAGS="-march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16"
export ARCH_LINK="-march=armv7-a -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8"
export CPPFLAGS=" ${ARCH_FLAGS} -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 "
export CXXFLAGS=" ${ARCH_FLAGS} -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -frtti -fexceptions "
export CFLAGS=" ${ARCH_FLAGS} -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 "
export LDFLAGS=" ${ARCH_LINK} "
```

And then run your configure script:

```
./Configure android-armv7
```

And then build

```
PATH=$TOOLCHAIN_PATH:$PATH make
```

You should see that it is using `arm-linux-androideabi-gcc` instead of `gcc`

To build for the old armeabi:

```
tar xzvf ~/Downloads/openssl-1.0.1g.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.1g
export NDK=~/android-ndk-r9d
$NDK/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-9 --toolchain=arm-linux-androideabi-4.6 --install-dir=`pwd`/android-toolchain-arm
export TOOLCHAIN_PATH=`pwd`/android-toolchain-arm/bin
export TOOL=arm-linux-androideabi
export NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME=${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/${TOOL}
export CC=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-gcc
export CXX=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-g++
export LINK=${CXX}
export LD=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-ld
export AR=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-ar
export RANLIB=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-ranlib
export STRIP=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-strip
export ARCH_FLAGS="-mthumb"
export ARCH_LINK=
export CPPFLAGS=" ${ARCH_FLAGS} -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 "
export CXXFLAGS=" ${ARCH_FLAGS} -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -frtti -fexceptions "
export CFLAGS=" ${ARCH_FLAGS} -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 "
export LDFLAGS=" ${ARCH_LINK} "
./Configure android
make clean
PATH=$TOOLCHAIN_PATH:$PATH make
```

to build for x86 :

```
tar xzvf ~/Downloads/openssl-1.0.1g.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.1g
export NDK=~/android-ndk-r9d
$NDK/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-9 --toolchain=x86-4.6 --install-dir=`pwd`/android-toolchain-x86
export TOOLCHAIN_PATH=`pwd`/android-toolchain-x86/bin
export TOOL=i686-linux-android
export NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME=${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/${TOOL}
export CC=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-gcc
export CXX=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-g++
export LINK=${CXX}
export LD=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-ld
export AR=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-ar
export RANLIB=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-ranlib
export STRIP=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-strip
export ARCH_FLAGS="-march=i686 -msse3 -mstackrealign -mfpmath=sse"
export ARCH_LINK=
export CPPFLAGS=" ${ARCH_FLAGS} -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 "
export CXXFLAGS=" ${ARCH_FLAGS} -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -frtti -fexceptions "
export CFLAGS=" ${ARCH_FLAGS} -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 "
export LDFLAGS=" ${ARCH_LINK} "
./Configure android-x86
make clean
PATH=$TOOLCHAIN_PATH:$PATH make
```

Comment: /Users/alex/Downloads/openssl-1.0.1e/android-toolchain-arm/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar  r ../libcrypto.a cryptlib.o mem.o mem_dbg.o cversion.o ex_data.o cpt_err.o ebcdic.o uid.o o_time.o o_str.o o_dir.o o_fips.o o_init.o fips_ers.o mem_clr.o
/Users/alex/Downloads/openssl-1.0.1e/android-toolchain-arm/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar: ../libcrypto.a: Malformed archive
make[1]: *** [../libcrypto.a] Error 1
make: *** [build_crypto] Error 1

Comment: I'm getting a "libcrypto.a: Malformed archive" error just like the previous comment. Are you sure this is working?

Comment: If getting "cp cannot create regular file No such file or directory in openssl" the follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23343345/getting-cp-cannot-create-regular-file-no-such-file-or-directory-in-openssl/23356652#23356652

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the delay. I don't check my emails regularly.  I just re-tested with Ubuntu 14.04LTS, android-ndk-r9d and openssl-1.0.1g, and it worked for me.

Comment: I just tried the same exact steps to compile libssl.a and libcrypto.a for Android armeabi on Mac OSX 10.9 (Mavericks) and again, it works for me.

Comment: I try to build the shared libs running `./Configure android-armv7 shared`. The problem is that this creates a versioned shared lib (libssl.so.1.0.0) . Versioned libraries are not supported by Android. Do you know how to turn off this behavior?

Comment: Building x86 does not work for me on Mac. Lots of undefined reference.

Comment: You save my day!!! Especially for old arm target.
x86 - not worked for me by this tutorial, but x86 and armv7 builds without problems if follow to this tutorial: http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android

Comment: @SteelFedeX : did you do `./Configure android-x86` ?

Comment: @SteelFedeX: I tried compiling `openssl-1.0.1i` using my own instructions on Ubuntu 14.04 using `android-ndk-r9d`, and it worked. I got libcrypto.a  libssl.a compiled for android-x86.

Comment: @mchiasson: you are right! Seems I simply forgot to do ./Configure android-x86(armv7). Thank you =)

Comment: Late to the party, but messages like `libcrypto.a: Malformed archive` can usually be solved by a `make clean` before `make`

Comment: Thank you Cogwirrel. This makes perfect sence. I had no idea why people were getting this error message to begin with.

Comment: worked for me using ubuntu tls 14.0 ,ndk8b  and openSSL 1.0.2c..@mchiasson thanks you so much

Comment: @VyshakhAmarnath You're very welcome. Glad I could help!

Comment: @tmanthey: use rpl to change SONAME http://computervisionandjava.blogspot.cz/2015/05/trouble-with-versioned-shared-libraries.html

Comment: if I could I will give you 100 up votes. Your tutorial worked, not like the one provided by OpenSSL for Android, which cost me 1 day and loads of nerves. Legend man, legend... :)

Comment: Were you able to successfully build OpenSSL 1.1.0c Android ARMv7a with ``clang`` and not ``gcc``?

Comment: @Toochka I unfortunately never tried. Do you have any trouble getting this particular version with this particular compiler to work?

Comment: I was able to build it using gcc and setenv-android.sh script. Still need to try building with clang

Comment: @Toochka is there a reason why you can't compile your program with clang and link it against libssl.so+libcrypto.so compiled with GCC? unless you are not using the same c library, it should work.

Comment: @mchiasson how can we configure for x86_64, i tried same as x86 but got error apps/apps.o:apps.c:function fileno_stdin: error: undefined reference to 'stdin'

Answer (score 15):

In OpenSSL 1.0.1e, all I need to do is:

```
CC=~/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc ./Configure android-armv7
ANDROID_DEV=~/android-ndk-r9//platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr make build_libs
```

Comment: set_key.c:398:17: error: unsupported inline asm: input with type 'unsigned long' matching output with type 'unsigned int'
                *(k++)=ROTATE(t2,30)&0xffffffffL;
                       ~~~~~~~^~~~~~
./des_locl.h:170:19: note: expanded from macro 'ROTATE'

Comment: James. Thank you for the tip. I created a shell file with the above 4 lines. The only thing I needed was to add "export " in front of CC and ANDROID_DEV. Just built 1.0.1g.

Comment: i was getting an obscure "libcrypto.a: member at N is not an ELF object" - this was because configure was picking up my Xcode toolchain, so i needed to export AR=.../arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-ar and export RANLIB=.../arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-ranlib

Comment: I had to add empty CROSS_COMPILE: `CROSS_COMPILE= CC="$ndkdir/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc" ./Configure`

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to the instructions posted here, plus some other additions, I've made an automated script which compiles the latest OpenSSL library for Android with support for: armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86, x86_64 and arm64-v8a:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
#@author Aleksandar Gotev (alex.gotev@mobimesh.it)
#Hints and code taken also from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929773/compiling-the-latest-openssl-for-android

if [ "$#" -ne 6 ]
then
    echo "Usage:"
    echo "./openssl-build <ANDROID_NDK_PATH> <OPENSSL_SOURCES_PATH> <ANDROID_TARGET_API> \\"
    echo "                <ANDROID_TARGET_ABI> <GCC_VERSION> <OUTPUT_PATH>"
    echo
    echo "Supported target ABIs: armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86, x86_64, arm64-v8a"
    echo
    echo "Example using GCC 4.8, NDK 10e, OpenSSL 1.0.2d and Android API 21 for armeabi-v7a."
    echo "./openssl-build /home/user/android-ndk-r10e \\"
    echo "                /home/user/openssl-1.0.2d \\"
    echo "                21 \\"
    echo "                armeabi-v7a \\"
    echo "                4.8 \\"
    echo "                /home/user/output/armeabi-v7a"
    exit 1
fi

NDK_DIR=$1
OPENSSL_BASE_FOLDER=$2
OPENSSL_TARGET_API=$3
OPENSSL_TARGET_ABI=$4
OPENSSL_GCC_VERSION=$5
OPENSSL_OUTPUT_PATH=$6

NDK_MAKE_TOOLCHAIN="$NDK_DIR/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh"
OPENSSL_TMP_FOLDER="/tmp/openssl"
rm -rf "$OPENSSL_TMP_FOLDER"
mkdir -p "$OPENSSL_TMP_FOLDER"
cp -r ${OPENSSL_BASE_FOLDER} ${OPENSSL_TMP_FOLDER}

function build_library {
    mkdir -p ${OPENSSL_OUTPUT_PATH}
    export PATH=$TOOLCHAIN_PATH:$PATH
    make && make install
    rm -rf ${OPENSSL_TMP_FOLDER}
    echo "Build completed! Check output libraries in ${OPENSSL_OUTPUT_PATH}"
}

if [ "$OPENSSL_TARGET_ABI" == "armeabi-v7a" ]
then
    ${NDK_MAKE_TOOLCHAIN} --platform=android-${OPENSSL_TARGET_API} \
                          --toolchain=arm-linux-androideabi-${OPENSSL_GCC_VERSION} \
                          --install-dir="${OPENSSL_TMP_FOLDER}/android-toolchain-arm"
    export TOOLCHAIN_PATH="${OPENSSL_TMP_FOLDER}/android-toolchain-arm/bin"
    export TOOL=arm-linux-androideabi
    export NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME=${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/${TOOL}
    export CC=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-gcc
    export CXX=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-g++
    export LINK=${CXX}
    export LD=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-ld
    export AR=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-ar
    export RANLIB=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-ranlib
    export STRIP=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-strip
    export ARCH_FLAGS="-march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16"
    export ARCH_LINK="-march=armv7-a -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8"
    export CPPFLAGS=" ${ARCH_FLAGS} -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 "
    export CXXFLAGS=" ${ARCH_FLAGS} -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -frtti -fexceptions "
    export CFLAGS=" ${ARCH_FLAGS} -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 "
    export LDFLAGS=" ${ARCH_LINK} "
    cd ${OPENSSL_TMP_FOLDER}
    ./Configure android-armv7 --openssldir=${OPENSSL_OUTPUT_PATH}
    build_library

elif [ "$OPENSSL_TARGET_ABI" == "arm64-v8a" ]
then
    ${NDK_MAKE_TOOLCHAIN} --platform=android-${OPENSSL_TARGET_API} \
                          --toolchain=aarch64-linux-android-4.9 \
                          --install-dir="${OPENSSL_TMP_FOLDER}/android-toolchain-arm64"
    export TOOLCHAIN_PATH="${OPENSSL_TMP_FOLDER}/android-toolchain-arm64/bin"
    export TOOL=aarch64-linux-android
    export NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME=${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/${TOOL}
    export CC=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-gcc
    export CXX=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-g++
    export LINK=${CXX}
    export LD=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-ld
    export AR=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-ar
    export RANLIB=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-ranlib
    export STRIP=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-strip
    export ARCH_FLAGS=
    export ARCH_LINK=
    export CPPFLAGS=" ${ARCH_FLAGS} -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 "
    export CXXFLAGS=" ${ARCH_FLAGS} -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -frtti -fexceptions "
    export CFLAGS=" ${ARCH_FLAGS} -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 "
    export LDFLAGS=" ${ARCH_LINK} "
    cd ${OPENSSL_TMP_FOLDER}
    ./Configure android --openssldir=${OPENSSL_OUTPUT_PATH}
    build_library

elif [ "$OPENSSL_TARGET_ABI" == "armeabi" ]
then
    ${NDK_MAKE_TOOLCHAIN} --platform=android-${OPENSSL_TARGET_API} \
                          --toolchain=arm-linux-androideabi-${OPENSSL_GCC_VERSION} \
                          --install-dir="${OPENSSL_TMP_FOLDER}/android-toolchain-arm"
    export TOOLCHAIN_PATH="${OPENSSL_TMP_FOLDER}/android-toolchain-arm/bin"
    export TOOL=arm-linux-androideabi
    export NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME=${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/${TOOL}
    export CC=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-gcc
    export CXX=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-g++
    export LINK=${CXX}
    export LD=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-ld
    export AR=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-ar
    export RANLIB=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-ranlib
    export STRIP=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-strip
    export ARCH_FLAGS="-mthumb"
    export ARCH_LINK=
    export CPPFLAGS=" ${ARCH_FLAGS} -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 "
    export CXXFLAGS=" ${ARCH_FLAGS} -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -frtti -fexceptions "
    export CFLAGS=" ${ARCH_FLAGS} -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 "
    export LDFLAGS=" ${ARCH_LINK} "
    cd ${OPENSSL_TMP_FOLDER}
    ./Configure android --openssldir=${OPENSSL_OUTPUT_PATH}
    build_library

elif [ "$OPENSSL_TARGET_ABI" == "x86" ]
then
    ${NDK_MAKE_TOOLCHAIN} --platform=android-${OPENSSL_TARGET_API} \
                          --toolchain=x86-${OPENSSL_GCC_VERSION} \
                          --install-dir="${OPENSSL_TMP_FOLDER}/android-toolchain-x86"
    export TOOLCHAIN_PATH="${OPENSSL_TMP_FOLDER}/android-toolchain-x86/bin"
    export TOOL=i686-linux-android
    export NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME=${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/${TOOL}
    export CC=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-gcc
    export CXX=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-g++
    export LINK=${CXX}
    export LD=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-ld
    export AR=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-ar
    export RANLIB=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-ranlib
    export STRIP=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-strip
    export ARCH_FLAGS="-march=i686 -msse3 -mstackrealign -mfpmath=sse"
    export ARCH_LINK=
    export CPPFLAGS=" ${ARCH_FLAGS} -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 "
    export CXXFLAGS=" ${ARCH_FLAGS} -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -frtti -fexceptions "
    export CFLAGS=" ${ARCH_FLAGS} -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 "
    export LDFLAGS=" ${ARCH_LINK} "
    cd ${OPENSSL_TMP_FOLDER}
    ./Configure android-x86 --openssldir=${OPENSSL_OUTPUT_PATH}
    build_library

elif [ "$OPENSSL_TARGET_ABI" == "x86_64" ]
then
    ${NDK_MAKE_TOOLCHAIN} --platform=android-${OPENSSL_TARGET_API} \
                          --toolchain=x86_64-4.9 \
                          --install-dir="${OPENSSL_TMP_FOLDER}/android-toolchain-x86_64"
    export TOOLCHAIN_PATH="${OPENSSL_TMP_FOLDER}/android-toolchain-x86_64/bin"
    export TOOL=x86_64-linux-android
    export NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME=${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/${TOOL}
    export CC=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-gcc
    export CXX=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-g++
    export LINK=${CXX}
    export LD=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-ld
    export AR=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-ar
    export RANLIB=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-ranlib
    export STRIP=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-strip
    export CPPFLAGS=" ${ARCH_FLAGS} -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 "
    export CXXFLAGS=" ${ARCH_FLAGS} -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -frtti -fexceptions "
    export CFLAGS=" ${ARCH_FLAGS} -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 "
    export LDFLAGS=" ${ARCH_LINK} "
    cd ${OPENSSL_TMP_FOLDER}
    ./Configure linux-x86_64 --openssldir=${OPENSSL_OUTPUT_PATH}
    build_library

else
    echo "Unsupported target ABI: $OPENSSL_TARGET_ABI"
    exit 1
fi
```

Script docs: https://github.com/alexbbb/pjsip-android-builder#build-only-openssl

For the last version check: https://github.com/alexbbb/pjsip-android-builder/blob/master/openssl-build

Comment: IMHO your post would sit better as a comment on the OP. If you want to keep it as an answer you could outline what are your additions to the previous answers.

Comment: Unfortunately this script does not work - I get error "no such file or directory" in every cd ${OPENSSL_TMP_FOLDER} for each abi. is this a general copy/paste error? which variable did you really mean? the ./Configure scripts sits in OPENSSL_HOME not in TMP?

Comment: This is too cool, I used the script ./openssl-build from the git you posted with openssl-1.0.2g, ndk-r12b, target 15 for 32bit & 21 for 64bit. Though it failed on ubuntu 16.04 but successfully compiled ABI x86, x86_64, mips, mips64, arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a & armeabi on OSX 10.11.6. But note compilation for the latest openssl-1.1.0 failed.

Comment: Note that all arch built excerpt mips64, the script contains an invalid parameter android-mips64 @ line 215 ./Configure android-mips64 --openssldir=${OPENSSL_OUTPUT_PATH}

Comment: script works very good. 
while executing found some issues and all these are due to wrong parameters passed.

Answer (score 3):

I glued together some useful advices here to a build environment for OpenSSL for Android which works for me.

- Supports build for multiple architectures - ARM, ARMv7, X86
- Uses OpenSSL source codes
- Integrated with Android.mk build
- Contains pre-compiled OpenSSL 1.0.2h (use if you want or compile your own)

https://github.com/ph4r05/android-openssl

Answer (score 1):

In case someone encounters the problem of using vulnerable version of OpenSSL (`< 1.0.2f/1.0.1r`) in one of the native libraries, I add some more details and instructions.

Preconditions: Android NDK need to be configured first.

1. First of all, download the `OpenSSL` compatible version (`> 1.0.2f/1.0.1r`).
2. Download two scripts from [this link](https://github.com/taskworld/openssl-mobile/tree/master/android). In case someone wonders what they do (and you should - it is a cryptographic library!!!): They build the `OpenSSL` library for every android ABI processor architecture (`armeabi`, `x86`, `mips`, etc...)
3. Modify setenv-android-mod.sh -> line `18` with the ndk version
4. Modify setenv-android-mod.sh -> line `40` with the Android API version
5. Modify build-all-arch.sh -> line `7` with the folder name of the `OpenSSL` library (in my case it was `openssl-1.0.1t`)
6. After successful build, inside the folder `dist` the libraries will be present

To add the `openSSL` to project as prebuilt static libraries, create:

1. `openssl` folder under `jni` directory containing `lib/` (which contain the `.a` files for the supported architectures),
2. `include/` which has the necessary includes (you can find that under the openssl version you downloaded, be aware that some of the header files are symbolic links)
3. Modify `Android.mk` inside `jni` folder adding the following:

   ```
   include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
   LOCAL_MODULE := libssl
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libssl.a
   include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
   include $(CLEAR_VARS)
   LOCAL_MODULE := libcrypto
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libcrypto.a
   include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
   ```

Then, to use the library within another `jni` module add the following to it's `Android.mk` file:

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../openssl/include
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libssl libcrypto
```

Comment: the setenv-android.sh doesnt work for osx enviornments as it doesnt save teh enviorments!

Comment: It should, this is just a `bash` script. Make sure the script is in correct path and `openssl` library is in correct path.

Comment: Bash script is in the home directory of openssl and on Yosemetie OSX it doesnt set the env paths :(

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't solve your problem, but perhaps it will help. A google groups post where they have successfully compiled OpenSSL 1.0.1 beta2 for Android.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-security-discuss/5-_gCAmEo-M

This might also help, an open source project that builds 1.0.0a for Android:

https://github.com/eighthave/openssl-android

Comment: Thanks Cristy, I already found the github link and following the same. In this link steps are given for Open SSL compilation for the android https://github.com/fries/android-external-openssl/blob/master/README.android

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it for openssl-1.0.2g:

```
$ rm -rf openssl-1.0.2g/
$ tar xzf openssl-1.0.2g.tar.gz
$ chmod a+x setenv-android.sh
$ . ./setenv-android.sh ---> Note: make sure in the same folder of your openssl-1.0.2g
$ cd openssl-1.0.2g/

$ perl -pi -e 's/install: all install_docs install_sw/install: install_docs install_sw/g' Makefile.org

$ ./config shared no-ssl2 no-ssl3 no-comp no-hw no-engine --openssldir=<Path of your OpenSSL> 

$ make depend
$ make clean
$ make all
before make install, ---Delete the "include" folder (path/of/your/openssl-1.0.2g/include)  or you may move it to another directory for safe keeping. 
$ make install
```

Make sure that you input the right NDK paths into your setenv-android.sh or else you will have errors.

Example for this build I used Android NDK vr10b (http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk32-r10b-darwin-x86.tar.bz2) 
 and used the ff path values inside my setenv-android.sh file:

```
_ANDROID_NDK="android-ndk-r10b" (Line 12)
_ANDROID_EABI="arm-linux-androideabi-4.8"(Line 16)
_ANDROID_API="android-19"(Line 24)
```

Reference:
https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android

**Note --->** 
I created a github commit to answer this question, please see: https://github.com/rjmangubat23/OpenSSL

I uploaded the different scripts for setenv-android.sh onto my github, cause you will need different type of scripts for different architectures:

For x86: https://github.com/rjmangubat23/OpenSSL/tree/master/x86

For ArmV7: https://github.com/rjmangubat23/OpenSSL/tree/master/ArmV7

Download Openssl here: ftp://ftp.openssl.org/source

Download Complete list of Android NDK files here: https://github.com/taka-no-me/android-cmake/blob/master/ndk_links.md

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this script](https://github.com/stdchpie/android-openssl) to compile openssl under Windows 7 + Cygwin. Everything you need is only change location of ndk and choose android api version.

My way step by step (Win 7 x64 + Cygwin + ndk r10c)

1. Copy file `setenv-android-mod.sh` and `build-all-arch.sh` to your openssl directory.
2. Modify file `build-all-arch.sh`

   - `cd openssl-1.0.1j` to `#cd openssl-1.0.1j` (line 56)
   - `cd ..` to `#cd ..` (line 80)
3. Modify file `setend-android-mod.sh`

   - `_ANDROID_NDK="android-ndk-r10c-x64"` change to your ndk version (line 18)
   - `_ANDROID_API="android-19"` change to your api version (line 40)
   - `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT="d:/work/android/android-ndk-r10c-x64"` specify your dir (line 42)
   - `ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN="d:/work/android/android-ndk-r10c-x64/toolchains"` specify your dir (line 43)
   - `export CROSS_COMPILE="aarch64-linux-android-"` to `export CROSS_COMPILE="$ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN/aarch64-linux-android-"` (line 219), change same lines 225, 231, 237, 243 - just add `$ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN/` to the cross compile path.

Run `build-all-arch.sh`.

All libraries (`*.so`) will be located in `/prebuilt/` dir.

P.S. I had a few more errors because of wrong symlinks, but everything was fine after executing the following command `export CYGWIN="winsymlinks:native"` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648819/how-to-make-symbolic-link-with-cygwin-in-windows-7) for details.

Answer (score 0):

This problem and many others like it caused me a week or so of mucking about, but I finally cracked it so I thought I'd share my solution. OpenSSL can be compiled for 21+ and work on Android 4.03 devices if you are willing to hack the code. We use libcurl, so wanted to be up to date. The steps are a bit complex:

First up ensure you have a buildable version of libcurl. I recommend as a good starting point https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x-3rd-party-libs-src

They keep up to date build scripts.

Firstly hack the android.ini in "build" to version 21

Next up I had to add the following stub functions to the jni project somewhere:

```
// SPECIAL API 21+ functions required for android to build on newer platform targets.

float strtof (const char* str, char** endptr)
{
    return (float)strtod(str, endptr);
}

int __isnanf(float x)
{
    return (x != x);
}

double atof (const char* s)
{
    double rez = 0, fact = 1;
    if (*s == '-'){
        s++;
        fact = -1;
    };
    for (int point_seen = 0; *s; s++){
        if (*s == '.'){
            point_seen = 1;
            continue;
        };
        int d = *s - '0';
        if (d >= 0 && d <= 9){
            if (point_seen) fact /= 10.0f;
            rez = rez * 10.0f + (float)d;
        };
    };
    return rez * fact;
}

void srandom(unsigned int seed)
{
    std::srand(seed);
}

static unsigned long _next = 1;

void srand(unsigned int seed)
{
    _next = seed;
}

long random()
{
    return rand();
}

int rand()
{
    _next = _next * 1103515245 + 12345;
    return (unsigned int)(_next/65536) % 32768;
}

/* the default is bsd */
__sighandler_t signal(int s, __sighandler_t f)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Note the signal function could be better, but for us it isn't important. This stops the dreaded "cannot locate symbol" errors on 4.03 devices caused by changes to the headers in 5+ (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/RjO9WmG9pfE).

Next up download the tar.gz for the version of openssl you want to build and unpack it somewhere. Edit crypto/ui/ui_openssl.c and crypto/des/read_pwd.c and ensure that the #defines for tcsetattr are not used. I used a brute force #if 0 and #if 1 - note this should be possible by twiddling the preprocessor, but I gave up at this point. If anyone feels like sharing the correct magic please do!

Now you need to re-tar up the file into the tarballs file (making sure you get it root folder in there:

and run (in my case)

shasum -a 512 curl-7.50.0.tar.gz > ../src/curl/SHA512SUMS

This will allow the cocos2d ./build.sh to run. Something like:

./build.sh -p=android --libs=openssl,curl --arch=armv7 --mode=release

Finally - and this caught me out in terms of making a universal .a file, but is not directly part of the question, ensure you use a version that doesn't use NEON instructions. Tegra 2 devices apparently have FPU but no NEON. I think this can be done using -mfpu=vfp as a compiler flag, but I chose to just use the armv5 build instead, as performance is not really important to me in this area (and I have had enough nasty real world surprises from this already).

In the end you should get a nice .a that works everywhere, and can be used in projects targeting the latest and greatest Android. Now if only someone from the OpenSSL project can read this and fix the project so it understands android stuff released 2 years ago!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to build OpenSSL on Windows using Cygwin and Android NDK

1. Download and extract OpenSSL source
2. Download script from https://github.com/pstanoev/OpenSSL-For-Android
3. Run `cmd` with Administrator user and execute

   `SET CYGWIN=winsymlinks:nativestrict`
4. In same cmd window, open Cygwin:

   `cygwin.bat`
5. Make script executable:

   `chmod +x *.sh`
6. In Cygwin execute:

   `/cygdrive/c/dev/openssl-source/openssl-build.sh /cygdrive/c/dev/android-ndk-r12b /cygdrive/c/dev/openssl-source/openssl-1.0.2j 15 armeabi-v7a 4.9 /home/user/openssl`

   - Modify for your locations of Android NDK and sources
7. Copy libcrypto.so and include/* files to this module. Use `cp -r` for copy to follow links.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [PJSIP Build For Android with Integration of G729 Codec](https://medium.com/@shehrazjazib/pjsip-build-for-android-with-integration-of-g729-codec-7d677ea68373) for compiling latest Openssl for Android. It is quite well explained.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: at least this link  explain much better than the other ...

Comment: This recipe uses a very old version of NDK.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these instructions may help :)

1: Download Android NDK (version ndk-r13b) from this url:

```
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r13b-linux-x86_64.zip
```

2: Extract NDK to /home/Android.

3: Download the cross compilation setup script from this URL:

```
https://wiki.openssl.org/images/7/70/Setenv-android.sh
```

4: Make following changes in the Setenv-android.sh script:

```
a: Add the following line to the start of the script
        
        ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/home/Android/android-ndk-r13b

b: Modify _ANDROID_NDK="android-ndk-r13".

c: Modify _ANDROID_EABI="arm-linux-androideabi-4.9"

d: Modify _ANDROID_API="android-23"
```

5: Download the openssl (version 1.0.2n) from this url:

```
https://www.openssl.org/source/old/1.0.2/openssl-1.0.2n.tar.gz
```

6: Extract the downloaded tarball.

7: Open new terminal window and navigate to extracted directory.

8: Move the Setenv-android.sh script to this directory and execute the following commands:

```
chmod a+x Setenv-android.sh
source ./Setenv-android.sh
```

9: Run the following command (to configure OpenSSL sources to build for Android):

```
./Configure shared android
```

10: Execute following command to build libcrypto and libssl shared libraries.

```
make CALC_VERSIONS="SHLIB_COMPAT=; SHLIB_SOVER=" build_libs
```

11: Let the build complete successfully.

Answer (score 0):

With NDK v22 and openssl-1.0.2o:

```
export PATH=$(echo -n $ANDROID_NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/*/bin):$PATH
./Configure android-x86 no-asm
make clean build_libs AR="llvm-ar r" RANLIB="llvm-ranlib" CC=i686-linux-android19-clang CFLAG="-fPIC -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -D__ANDROID_API__=19 -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall -I$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/sysroot/usr/include -I$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/sysroot/usr/include/i686-linux-android"
mkdir -p x86/lib x86/include/openssl
cp lib*.a x86/lib
cp include/openssl/* x86/include/openssl
```

builds static libs for x86