# android open SSL 1.0.1g compile

Tags: android, c, ssl, android-ndk

My project has dependency on openSSL.

so far i have been using the pre compiled static library from here
https://github.com/guardianproject/openssl-android

i Just need to call the ndk-build to compile.

But due to heartbleed bug in openSSl, i need to update static library for openSSL version 1.0.1G. i cant find any precompiled library in the internet and its not safe too.

So im looking for the instructions to build the static library by myself from this link
https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1g.tar.gz

so far i followed the instructions from here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18577811/3467481

until the make command.

But issuing ndk-build will do nothing. maybe bcz there is no manifest file and make files.
Im not sure how to configure them nor i can not find proper instructions.

Comment: i added the empty manifest file, make files for apps, crypto ,ssl  and JNI folder from the previous ports. but stuck with error when building using ndk-build. Im not a C developer to understand it properly.