# OpenSSL Compiled to Run on Android x86 Architecture

Tags: android, gcc, openssl, makefile, cross-compiling

I've been knocking my head against the wall this one: I've gotten openssl to compile just fine for the android armeabi architecture, but there's so much less aid for x86, and nothing on it that I can find on openSSL's site.

Something I eventually found was an intel article (https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-intel-advanced-encryption-standard-new-instructions-on-android#openssl) on using openssl for x86 architecture's, and after creating a standalone toolchain, and going through their provided code and fixing some of it, I'm at the point where make will get almost all the way through compilation before failing with a bunch of undefined reference to 'XXX' statements. I cannot figure out how to get past this at this point, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I apologize if this ends up being somewhat trivial, I am very new to make.

Trace:

> /private/tmp/my-android-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.6/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld: ts.o: in function ts_main:ts.c(.text+0x1e8a): error: undefined reference to 'TS_RESP_set_tst_info'
>   /private/tmp/my-android-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.6/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld: ts.o: in function ts_main:ts.c(.text+0x1ea2): error: undefined reference to 'TS_TST_INFO_free'
>   /private/tmp/my-android-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.6/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld: srp.o: in function srp_verify_user:srp.c(.text+0xb3): error: undefined reference to 'SRP_create_verifier'
>   /private/tmp/my-android-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.6/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld: srp.o: in function srp_create_user:srp.c(.text+0x1e3): error: undefined reference to 'SRP_create_verifier'
>   /private/tmp/my-android-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.6/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld: srp.o: in function srp_main:srp.c(.text+0x1014): error: undefined reference to 'X509_get_default_cert_area'
>   /private/tmp/my-android-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.6/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld: srp.o: in function srp_main:srp.c(.text+0x10c0): error: undefined reference to 'SRP_get_default_gN'
>   /private/tmp/my-android-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.6/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld: srp.o: in function srp_main:srp.c(.text+0x16dd): error: undefined reference to 'TXT_DB_insert'

Edit:
Sorry, by the fact that they were specifying eabi in the setenv script, I thought that meant you could only select one of the ARM eabi's, since the other architectures weren't specified with it. I've been to openSSL's instructions on android for compiling ARM, but I wasn't aware it would also function for x86. If that's the case then I feel dumb.
I set the --sysroot option to the sysroot on the android independent keychain.

These are the commands I used for x86 compilation, as per the intel article on the subject.

```
    export CC="$STANDALONE_TOOCHAIN_PATH/bin/i686-linux-android-gcc -mtune=atom -march=atom --sysroot=$STANDALONE_TOOCHAIN_PATH/sysroot"
    export AR=$STANDALONE_TOOCHAIN_PATH/bin/i686-linux-android-ar
    export RANLIB=/private/tmp/my-android-toolchain/bin/i686-li
    ./Configure android-x86 -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems I've figured it out. Using the code I posted (as the code in the article is slightly syntactically incorrect, but the idea is right) and after having made a custom android toolchain, I was able to run make successfully after a fresh installation of OpenSSL. My guess is that the work I did on it in order to compile the ARM architecture *.a and *.so files probably goofed something up when I went back to it for the x86 architecture.

If unsure of how to create a standalone toolchain (use the easy way option): http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html

Comment: With the number of errors and fixes required to use anything other than an ARM architecture with openssl's setenv script, I found this a much easier way to go about it.

Comment: "...My guess is that the work I did on it in order to compile the ARM architecture *.a and *.so files probably goofed something up..." - before changing platforms, you should probably run `make clean && make dclean`. That will clear the former platform's cruft.

Comment: In my case, I could go ahead by opening a new terminal. If you try to use the same terminal for your architecture builds, your path will become dirty.

Answer (score 3):

> but there's so much less aid for x86, and nothing on it that I can find on openSSL's site

I believe the OpenSSL wiki covers the topic: [OpenSSL and Android](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android).

---

> Something I eventually found was an intel article... on using openssl for x86 architecture

You simply select the correct abi. According to the Android wiki page, you adjust the following in the `setenv-android.sh` script:

- `_ANDROID_NDK` – the version of the NDK. For example, android-ndk-r8e
- `_ANDROID_EABI` – the version of the EABI tools. For example, arm-linux-androideabi-4.6
- `_ANDROID_API` – the API level. For example, android-14

There's an entire subsection on it at the wiki: [Adjust the Cross-Compile Script](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android#Adjust_the_Cross-Compile_Script). Please let us know if there are any gaps. (I tested it against ARM, but not x86).

There's plenty of ABI's to select. You probably want `x86-4.6` and `API 14` or `API 18`.

[image]

<strike>You *might* have to modify `Configure`, but it does not appear you are that far so its hard to say at the moment.</strike> You don't need to modify configure - the `android-x86` target is already present.

---

> /private/tmp/my-android-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.6/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld: ts.o:
>   in function ts_main:ts.c(.text+0x1e8a): error: undefined reference to 'TS_RESP_set_tst_info' /private/tmp/my-android-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.6/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld

This almost looks like you are missing `--sysroot`. Something is munged up for sure.

You should probably show us one of your compile line and a link line (what one of the C files looks like, not a dump of all of them).

Comment: Even after switching the eabi to an x86 folder and fixing the setenv script for path errors, running ./config still spits out that the project is "configured for android-armv7" followed by a failure on "make depend" stating that the command arm-linux-androideabi-gcc in /util/domd can't be found.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37043683/2210080 but this is for ArmV7. Just do the same procedure as what I did in the previous but use this particular setenv-android.sh script: https://github.com/rjmangubat23/OpenSSL/blob/master/x86/setenv-android.sh