# Compile OpenSSL 1.1.0 for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, openssl, cygwin

I'm trying to compile openssl-1.1.0 on Android by cygwin follow by this guidance:

[Compiling the latest OpenSSL for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929773/compiling-the-latest-openssl-for-android#)

But it's failed, this is the error :

```
crypto/aes/aes_ecb.c:10:20: fatal error: assert.h: No such file or directory
 #include <assert.h>
```

I'm using Android-ndk-r12b, Win10, cygwin 64 bit.

This is my pre-config before compiling:

```
export NDK=~/android-ndk-r12b
$NDK/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-21 --toolchain=arm-linux-androideabi-4.9 --install-dir=`pwd`/android-toolchain-arm
export TOOLCHAIN_PATH=`pwd`/android-toolchain-arm/bin
export TOOL=arm-linux-androideabi
export NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME=${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/${TOOL}
export CC=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-gcc
export CXX=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-g++
export LINK=${CXX}
export LD=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-ld
export AR=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-ar
export RANLIB=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-ranlib
export STRIP=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-strip
export ARCH_FLAGS="-mthumb"
export ARCH_LINK=
export CPPFLAGS=" ${ARCH_FLAGS} -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 "
export CXXFLAGS=" ${ARCH_FLAGS} -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -frtti -fexceptions "
export CFLAGS=" ${ARCH_FLAGS} -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 "
export LDFLAGS=" ${ARCH_LINK} "
./Configure android
PATH=$TOOLCHAIN_PATH:$PATH make
```

Please help to tell me where I'm wrong

EDIT:

Follow by jww's suggestion, I try with https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android

I changed some config in setenv-android.sh into:

```
-_ANDROID_NDK="android-ndk-r12b"
-_ANDROID_EABI="arm-linux-androideabi-4.9"
-_ANDROID_API="android-21"
```

To generate valid toolchains, I add "windows-x86_64" into 
for host in "linux-x86_64" "linux-x86" "darwin-x86_64" "darwin-x86"
Now it's:

```
for host in "linux-x86_64" "linux-x86" "darwin-x86_64" "darwin-x86" "windows-x86_64"
do
....
done
```

+Build openssl-1.1.0:

Error:

```
$ perl -pi -e 's/install: all install_docs install_sw/install: install_docs install_sw/g' Makefile.org
Can't open Makefile.org: No such file or directory.
```

EDIT 2:

I follow the wiki update by jww and it runs smoothly until this command:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -I /usr/local/ssl/include my_prog.c -o my_prog.exe -L /usr/local/ssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

If I use `$ANDROID_TOOCHAIN/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -I /usr/local/ssl/include my_prog.c -o my_prog.exe -L /usr/local/ssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto` , it doesn't understand `-I` and `my_prog.c`

I want to build openssl-1.1.0 for android but I don't know how to fix it. Please help

Comment: One of the simpler ways is to follow the instructions detailed at [OpenSSL and Android](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android) from the OpenSSL wiki. Is there a reason its not suitable for you?

Comment: I also tried compiling with setenv-android.sh but it's fail for openssl 1.1.0, that why I turn into this. Maybe I miss some config in setenv-android.sh, Thanks for your suggestion, I'll try again with that.

Comment: Does the build tell you the compiler command line for the failing command?

Comment: Yes, it tells me Can't open Makefile.org: No such file or directory when compiling this line:

$ perl -pi -e 's/install: all install_docs install_sw/install: install_docs install_sw/g' Makefile.org

Comment: @kairen - *"Can't open Makefile.org"* - It sounds like you are using OpenSSL 1.1.0. Skip that step; it only helps with the `make install` rule. Its not essential to the cross-compile build. I'll update the wiki soon.

Comment: @jww thanks, your wiki update will help alots

Comment: @jww I use android-ndk-r12b which only have "Window-x32-64" in Toolchains folder. In your setenv-android.sh, when setting ANDROID-TOOlCHAINS path, I see there is no window-x32-64 in line "for host in ....." , that makes toolchain path is empty on my environment, is it ok to add window-x32-64 to the loop "for host in...."?

Comment: @kairen - Yes, its OK. Send me the your changes, attribute them in `setenv` script, and I'll upload the new one for you. Or, you can request an account on the wiki and upload it.

Comment: @jww Thanks for your kind, I almost use the same config as in your setenv-android.sh, just change _ANDROID_NDK="android-ndk-r12b"
_ANDROID_EABI="arm-linux-androideabi-4.9" _ANDROID_API=21 and add "windows-x86_64" into for host in "linux-x86_64" "linux-x86" "darwin-x86_64" "darwin-x86" for valid ANDROID-TOOLCHAIN path. Is it enough to compile openssl 1.1.0 successfully ? And one thing, use "make depend" then "make all" will have same result with "make install" ?

Comment: I'm getting ther same behaviour even though I followed the wiki. Also the same behaviour for 1.0.1e

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to build OpenSSL 1.1.0g for Android with

```
android NDK android-ndk-r16b, centOS 6.9 64 bit OS.
```

as per https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android

and had the same problem

```
crypto/aes/aes_ecb.c:10:20: fatal error: assert.h: No such file or directory
 #include <assert.h>
```

After searching, I found that Updated NDK `android-ndk-r16b` has updated the `sysroot` to `android-ndk-r16b/sysroot` which contains the include directories but no library.

So the include path and the library path has changed

but the `setenv-android.sh` set the `sysroot` as

```
export ANDROID_SYSROOT="$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/platforms/$_ANDROID_API/$_ANDROID_ARCH"
```

But this is valid for android-ndk-r13b

**I can successfully build the OpenSSL with android-ndk-r13b.**

Comment: I still see same issue

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [this Github library](https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher/blob/master/android-database-sqlcipher/build-openssl-libraries.sh)

`setenv-android.sh` is not necessary. This really works.

Comment: Hi can you please share steps ?I am facing error on 'make build' command