# Issue OpenSSL library not found building PJSIP project for android ABIs

Tags: android, openssl, pjsip

I'm working on build PJSIP project for Android ABIs(armeabi, x86_64, x86) using OpenSSL on Ubuntu. I tired to build OpenSSL Android ABIs(armeabi, x86_64, x86) by the given steps on [PJSIP Documentation](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android), [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929773/compiling-the-latest-openssl-for-android) and [Github repo](https://github.com/VoiSmart/pjsip-android-builder/blob/master/openssl-build).

I have successfully build OpenSSL for Android ABIs and created static libraries (*.a). Now, with the created static libraries `(libCrypto.a and libssl.a)` I've started to build PJSIP project for Android ABIs and set OpenSSL directory path in `./Configure Android` as mentioned in their document for corresponded ABI.

When I'm looking generated logs in terminal I found the message "**OpenSSL library not found. OpenSSL disabled"**.

One thing I noticed that I'm working with (.a) library whereas I saw many suggestions are using `(libcrypto.so and libssl.so)`, if this is the issue then, I'd like to know the steps to generate `.so` library to build OpenSSL project.

Comment: are you built the library with ssl command? you want to build as TARGET_ABI=arm64-v8a ./configure-android --use-ndk-cflags --with-ssl=[your_openssl_path]/openssl-1.0.2a [pjsip_docs](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android#OpenSSLSupport)

Comment: Yes, I do same.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same exact issue [on Mac OS building for Android] and what I did to fix it is copy the outputs for the specific android arch I was doing to the lib folder of the openssl directory and it seems to have worked.

the files I copied were: libcrypto.a, libssl.a [not sure if I needed all of them, maybe someone knows??]

it is mentioned here as well:
[pjsip](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android#Features)

I only got all 4 of my architectures to build when I changed to no-shared on the openssl build

```
 ./Configure $SSL_TARGET $OPTIONS -fuse-ld="$TOOLCHAIN/$TRIBLE/bin/ld"   no-shared no-ssl2 no-ssl3 no-comp no-hw no-engine
make depend && make all && \
make install DESTDIR=$DESTDIR || exit 128
```

I also found a link that I think explained why I was getting the error when the shared option was used:

[openssl RPATHs](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#Using_RPATHs)