# fatal error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory while compiling openssl-1.1.0h

Tags: android, android-ndk, openssl, ndk-build

I am trying to compile open ssl for android.
I followed this link for compilation.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929773/compiling-the-latest-openssl-for-android

But i am stuck at this error immediately .

```
fatal error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory  #  include <sys/cdefs.h>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Followed another link which helped me to solve the issue.
**libc6-dev-i386** was not installed in my system.
After installing with this command  in my Ubuntu the errors were gone.

```
sudo apt-get install g++-multilib
```

[Answer from ubuntu link for reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470796/fatal-error-sys-cdefs-h-no-such-file-or-directory)