# Android Pjsip Video Call: After Video Call ended, app suddenly got crashed

Tags: android, pjsip, pjsua2

I have successfully implemented **SIP Video Call** using **Pjsip Library** and tested in **Samusng**, **Google Pixel** devices.

When I was testing it in **Nexus 5** and **Nexus 6**, it suddenly got crashed. When I checked the crash in Android Studio, it was in Pjsip library.

Here is the log:

```
09-11 11:09:54.673 201-201/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'google/hammerhead/hammerhead:6.0.1/M4B30Z/3437181:user/release-keys'
09-11 11:09:54.673 201-201/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '11'
09-11 11:09:54.673 201-201/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
09-11 11:09:54.673 201-201/? A/DEBUG: pid: 15354, tid: 15577, name: Thread-3252  >>> com.aanal.sip <<<
09-11 11:09:54.673 201-201/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x73006f
09-11 11:09:54.709 201-201/? A/DEBUG:     r0 0073006f  r1 b6cc1ec0  r2 0000010f  r3 9733927c
09-11 11:09:54.709 201-201/? A/DEBUG:     r4 95a748c4  r5 00200001  r6 95a748c4  r7 00000000
09-11 11:09:54.709 201-201/? A/DEBUG:     r8 95a74f88  r9 00000000  sl 97451310  fp 973b5d38
09-11 11:09:54.709 201-201/? A/DEBUG:     ip 00000001  sp 95a748a8  lr 98e3de51  pc 98e3cf92  cpsr 600f0030
09-11 11:09:54.738 201-201/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
09-11 11:09:54.738 201-201/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 000b4f92  /data/app/com.aanal.sip-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (_ZN4Swig8Director13JNIEnvWrapperD2Ev+13)
09-11 11:09:54.738 201-201/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 000b5e4d  /data/app/com.aanal.sip-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (_ZN17SwigDirector_Call11onCallStateERN2pj16OnCallStateParamE+112)
09-11 11:09:54.739 201-201/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 000e4add  /data/app/com.aanal.sip-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (_ZN2pj4Call18processStateChangeERNS_16OnCallStateParamE+68)
09-11 11:09:54.739 201-201/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 000da8b3  /data/app/com.aanal.sip-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (_ZN2pj8Endpoint13on_call_stateEiP11pjsip_event+34)
09-11 11:09:54.739 201-201/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 000f5cd7  /data/app/com.aanal.sip-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so
09-11 11:09:54.739 201-201/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00106985  /data/app/com.aanal.sip-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so
09-11 11:09:54.739 201-201/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 001069e5  /data/app/com.aanal.sip-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so
09-11 11:09:54.739 201-201/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 0010728f  /data/app/com.aanal.sip-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so
09-11 11:09:54.740 201-201/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 00104da1  /data/app/com.aanal.sip-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so
09-11 11:09:54.740 201-201/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 00122127  /data/app/com.aanal.sip-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (pjsip_dlg_on_tsx_state+78)
09-11 11:09:54.740 201-201/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 0011ef0d  /data/app/com.aanal.sip-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so
09-11 11:09:54.740 201-201/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 0011f2e5  /data/app/com.aanal.sip-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so
09-11 11:09:54.740 201-201/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 00120acf  /data/app/com.aanal.sip-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (pjsip_tsx_recv_msg+82)
09-11 11:09:54.740 201-201/? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 0012205b  /data/app/com.aanal.sip-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (pjsip_dlg_on_rx_request+374)
09-11 11:09:54.740 201-201/? A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 00122c25  /data/app/com.aanal.sip-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so
09-11 11:09:54.740 201-201/? A/DEBUG:     #15 pc 00115d31  /data/app/com.aanal.sip-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (pjsip_endpt_process_rx_data+168)
09-11 11:09:54.741 201-201/? A/DEBUG:     #16 pc 00115e93  /data/app/com.aanal.sip-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so
09-11 11:09:54.741 201-201/? A/DEBUG:     #17 pc 00118fa7  /data/app/com.aanal.sip-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (pjsip_tpmgr_receive_packet+702)
09-11 11:09:54.741 201-201/? A/DEBUG:     #18 pc 00119cfd  /data/app/com.aanal.sip-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so
09-11 11:09:54.741 201-201/? A/DEBUG:     #19 pc 0018e6bd  /data/app/com.aanal.sip-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (ioqueue_dispatch_read_event+292)
09-11 11:09:54.741 201-201/? A/DEBUG:     #20 pc 0018f25b  /data/app/com.aanal.sip-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (pj_ioqueue_poll+450)
09-11 11:09:54.741 201-201/? A/DEBUG:     #21 pc 00115c0d  /data/app/com.aanal.sip-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (pjsip_endpt_handle_events2+90)
09-11 11:09:54.741 201-201/? A/DEBUG:     #22 pc 000f6e75  /data/app/com.aanal.sip-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (pjsua_handle_events+32)
09-11 11:09:54.741 201-201/? A/DEBUG:     #23 pc 000f6e99  /data/app/com.aanal.sip-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so
09-11 11:09:54.742 201-201/? A/DEBUG:     #24 pc 0018fb41  /data/app/com.aanal.sip-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so
09-11 11:09:54.742 201-201/? A/DEBUG:     #25 pc 0003f45f  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+30)
09-11 11:09:54.742 201-201/? A/DEBUG:     #26 pc 00019b43  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
```

Can anyone help me throgh this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please visit [this](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android)
and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929773/compiling-the-latest-openssl-for-android)

**nexus 5 is not arm64 device**. You need to configure your `OpenSSL`  according to arm86.

Comment: @AnuragShrivastava Okay let me check.

Comment: @AnuragShrivastava, I have already built libopenh264.so based on 4 different architectures. arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, x86 and x86_64. Do you think this issue is because of this architecture problem?

Comment: Can you post your onCallState function? It looks like that is where the crash is happening.

Comment: override fun onCallState(prm: OnCallStateParam) {
        MyApp.observer.notifyCallState(this)
    }

Comment: @user8127814 I have used callbacks.