# OpenSSL in Android

Tags: android, openssl

Is the OpenSSL included in Android?
If so, how can I call OpenSSL functions such as AES encryption?

Comment: My question is whether the android include the OpenSSL code basically, not to support crypto package. I read how to build OpenSSL for android many times. I heard from someone that we can call a OpenSSL function without building, but I can't find the comment about it. I'm wondering it's true or not.

Comment: Do you actually need OpenSSL, or do you just want to do AES encryption?  If you just need AES, Android has better options than OpenSSL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some of the Helpful Links : 
[How to use Open SSL in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046573/how-to-use-openssl-library-in-the-android-application).
For AES encryption take a look at javax.crypto package which android supports. javax.crypto supports AES algorithm as well. Here is the link for that [javax.crypto in Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/package-summary.html). Make sure you do some research before asking question. At least try to present what you have tried and be specific about your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question "Is the OpenSSL included in Android?" is "No". OpenSSL is apparently not included by default in Android.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can easily compile the latest openSSL yourself if you're interested to go in this direction. You can follow my build instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929773/compiling-the-latest-openssl-for-android/)

Answer (score 1):

You can find that by using below code:

```
 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (Provider provider : Security.getProviders()) {
    builder.append("provider: ")
              .append(provider.getName())
            .append(" ")
            .append(provider.getVersion())
            .append("(")
            .append(provider.getInfo())
            .append(")\n");
}
String providers = builder.toString();
//now display the string on the screen or in the logs for debugging.
```

which will give you result like:

```
provider: GmsCore_OpenSSL1.0 (Android's OpenSSL-backed security provider)
provider: AndroidOpenSSL1.0 (Android's OpenSSL-backed security provider)
provider: DRLCertFactory1.0 (ASN.1, DER, PkiPath, PKCS7)
provider: BC1.49 (BouncyCastle Security Provider v1.49)
provider: Crypto1.0 (HARMONY (SHA1 digest; SecureRandom; SHA1withDSA signature))
provider: HarmonyJSSE1.0 (Harmony JSSE Provider)
provider: AndroidKeyStore1.0 (Android AndroidKeyStore security provider)
```

Also if want to implement you can compile your own openssl libarary(latest) and you have to write your own ndk code(in c/c++) with static import of this compiled  openssl library .