# You are using a vulnerable version of OpenSSL alert for CSipSimple

Tags: android, android-ndk, openssl, csip-simple

I have same issue with this link:
[How to update OpenSSL version in CSipSimple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36493508/how-to-update-openssl-version-in-csipsimple)

I get an error when I try to "make" with latest openssl version.
How can I find openssl for Csipsimple build?
Which should I use the ndk version?
Thank's

Comment: _"with latest openssl version"_. Exactly which version is that?

Comment: First trying: openssl 1.01t https://www.openssl.org/source/  Second trying: openssl 1.0.1s https://github.com/edwardlujunneng/openssl_android_build

Comment: Well, [according to Google](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6376725?hl=en), 1.01r and later should be supported. However, support for the 1.01 track from the OpenSSL developers will end on 2016-12-31, so it would be a good idea to switch to 1.02.

Comment: I believe "*How can I find openssl for Csipsimple build"* is off-topic for the site. Usually you are expected to find your own resources. There's no reason to ask someone here to Google for you. Perhaps you should visit a chat room and ask the question.

Comment: I don't think *"Which should I use the ndk version?"* is a useful question. When in doubt, use the latest NDK version, which is currently r12b. It seems like a better choice for questions would have been the one about the failed make. But you did not provide details, and you did not ask the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem with this way:

Dowloand openssl from this link: https://github.com/edwardlujunneng/openssl_android_build and move files to jni/openssl/source/ folder.

Copy .S files from old openssl folder and paste in to new openssl.

See details: https://github.com/r3gis3r/CSipSimple/issues/44